# Retrieve Product2 return null when query outside the loop

Tags: trigger

I have trigger on before insert on Opportunity Line Item.It need to query the Product2 field.

This is the current code;

```
 for(OpportunityLineItem oli : newList)
 {
    if(oli.automatedCreated==false)
    {
         mapProduct.put(oli.Product2ID, [select myfield 
                                           from Product2 
                                          where Id =: oli.Product2ID].myField); 
     }
  }
```

The mapProduct is returned in the code above.But it is query inside the loop which is not good practice so what I did is

```
 for(OpportunityLineItem oli : newList)
 {
     if(oli.automatedCreated==false)
     {          
        setProductId.add(oli.Product2ID);     
      }
  }  

   mapProduct =new Map<Id,Product2>([Select Id,myfield  from Product2  
                                      where Id in:setProductId ]);
```

But the `mapProduct` return null.Any idea why?

Comment: if my assumption is correct, in any case map can't be null it be empty or it will have values

Comment: in the first code , where the query inside the loop , the Product is exist. but if i query outside the loop there is no data available that is why it return null map.

Comment: can you add debug and check setProductId having value or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `oli.Product2Id` doesn't exist at before insert. The [field is not creatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm).  This field won't be populated until the record is saved.

You are better off locating the Product2 by traversing the relationship:

```
oli.pricebookEntry.Product2Id
```